# Intro to Algorithms: asymptotic function analyzation using max()

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

I'm reading "Introduction to Algorithms" 3rd edition by Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein Page 46.  The authors place formal upper and lower bounds on a function which is quadratic.   Can anyone explain where the values for $c_1$, $c_2$ and $n_0$ are taken?  I'm also confused why the $max$ function is used and it's parameters.

[image: text]

$max$ is used later as well in this paragraph.  Appreciate any guidance on why its used:

[image: text2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution provided by the books author and written in this form by myself.

[image: solution]

Answer (score 1):

e.g. in the last paragraph, $\max\{1,-b/a\}$ is used to guarantee a lower bound. In other words, when $-b/a$ is small, we still have $\max\{1,-b/a\} \ge 1$.

**UPDATE**

So let's assume $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ with $a>0$ and prove that $an+b = O\left(n^2\right)$. To do that, we let $c = a + |b|$ and $n_0 = \max\{1,-b/a\}$. Let's take any $n > n_0$ and show that $an+b \le cn^2 \iff cn^2 - an - b \ge 0$.

The parabola on the LHS is facing up (since $c>0$) and has a vertex at
$$
\tag{*}
\frac{-(-a)}{2c} = \frac{a}{2a+2|b|} < 1 < n_0 < n,
$$
which implies that we are in the increasing branch on the right of the vertex. (Note in (*) we used a part of the maximum.) As long at at $n_0$ the inequality holds, we are done.

Now, there are 2 cases.

**Case I.** $n_0 = 1 \iff 1 \ge -b/a \iff a \ge -b$.
At $n_0 = 1$, the LHS yields $$c-a-b = a+|b|-a-b = |b|-b \ge 0,$$ as desired.

**Case II.** $n_0 = -b/a \iff 1 \le -b/a \iff a \le -b$. Now, since $a>0$ we must have $b<0$ and $c = a-b$. Then, the LHS becomes
$$
c(-b/a)^2 - a(-b/a) - b = (a-b)\frac{b^2}{a^2} > 0.
$$

As you can see, without the maximum to separate the cases, you would not be able to argue in such a way.

Comment: Why is $-b/a$ chosen as a parameter?

Comment: @Nick please see the update